# R subset/filter returns no rows

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I'm sorry this is a too trivial question but:

Be it with dplyr or with base R, it's not possible to filter/subset based on the sum of the rows, despite it has the same class and type. In a all numeric columns data frame, i can subset every every column by a integer (1, eg), but that one with the rowsums.

```
library(dplyr)

x <- seq(-1, 1, 0.2)


#With dplyr

df <- data.frame(V1 = x, V2 = x, V3 = x, V4 = x, V5 = x)

df <- df %>% mutate(soma = rowSums(df))

df %>% filter(V1 == V2, V2==V3, V3 == V4, V4 == V5) #Works!

df %>% filter(V1 == 1) #Works!

df %>% filter(soma == 1) #Why this filter does not work?

class(df$V1)

class(df$soma)

typeof(df$V1)

typeof(df$soma)


#R base

df <- data.frame(V1 = x, V2 = x, V3 = x, V4 = x, V5 = x)

df$soma <- rowSums(df)

df[with(df, V1 == V2, V2==V3, V3 == V4, V4 == V5),] #Works!

df[df$V1 == 1,] #Works!

df[df$soma == 1,] #Why this filter does not work?

class(df$V1)

class(df$soma)

typeof(df$V1)

typeof(df$soma)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Floats are inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate); You cannot expect to compare floats as the math proves, especially if they are derived from calculations, which leads to rounding errors.

You need to specify some tolerance to compare floats to get a reasonable result.

```
df %>% filter(abs(soma - 1) < 0.00000000001)

#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 soma
#1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you type the following, you will notice that the 7th number in `soma` is not equal to `1`

```
print(df$soma[7], digit = 21)
[1] 1.0000000000000009
```

See this link to learn more about why this happens: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

One way to overcome this is to use the `round` function before filtering.

```
df %>%
  mutate(soma2 = round(soma)) %>%
  filter(soma2 == 1)
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 soma soma2
1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2    1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a machine-rounding error issue.  Check out

```
df %>% filter(abs(soma - 1) < 0.000001)
```

Your numbers are saved as doubles, so they have some rounding.  Save your numbers as integers (add an L after: `1L`, convert them, or allow for the machine rounding error in your calculations (as I did above).